# Can we add a link to the /privileges page in the 'What is reputation?' section of the FAQ?

Tags: feature-request, faq-suggestion

The 'What is reputation?' section of the [FAQ](https://askubuntu.com/faq) briefly explains what is reputation, how to earn it, and what privileges you can earn by having enough reputation. However, due to the nature of being a FAQ entry, it is not possible for it to go into too much detail about the different privileges.

However, there is a nice [page](https://askubuntu.com/privileges) on the site that does this (and is shown to users whenever they gain new privileges). I think that it would be useful to add a link to this privileges guide under this section of the FAQ. Besides when a notification about earning new privileges pops up, there is no easy way for new users to find this very helpful page.

Comment: I think you mean /privileges

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a reference to the page in the [faq](https://askubuntu.com/faq)

Comment: Shouldn't it go down in the section where it talks about rep?

Comment: @JorgeCastro We don't have access to that section

Comment: Yes, we only have access to the part in the beginning